Unable to open certain programs such as Pensela on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
I am having trouble opening certain applications such as pensela.
They appear on my app list as well as go on my dashboard when I add to favorites but whenever I try to open them (whether by clicking on them or using terminal, nothing happens).  I have tried purging & reinstalling without success.
I have looked at other answers for similar problems without success such as: 'Ubuntu Software' app not loading on 22.04
Did the killall snap-store; sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-software; etc.
The only thing that seems to work is sudo apt purge pensela.
I already restarted, tried looking at the System Monitor, & using terminal to open as suggested by: Certain programs won't open
I haven't tried everything here yet: Ubuntu Software not loading properly
I am a newbie so please help me.  Thanks.

The first step to debug this kind of issue is to try and start the program from a terminal; that's because, usually, error messages will appear on the terminal instead of being sent to a "void" where you can't see them; so try and run Pensela from the command line, and edit the errors that show up on the terminal into your question so that we can take a look at them

There is no deb nor snap package named 'pensela' in the Ubuntu repositories. So it is unclear what you installed, where it came from, how you installed it, and how you determined that you installed it correctly. That information in your question would also help a lot.

pensela --disable-gpu-sandbox
I encountered the same error while attempting to run pensela_1.2.5_amd64.deb.
Using the above command resolved the issue for me.
In your Ubuntu terminal, instead of running pensela, try pensela --disable-gpu-sandbox.
